# How to format float columns of dataframe to desired decimal places while writing into delimited file?

Tags: python, pandas, rounding

So my dataframe has a bunch of columns for pricings which hold values like 16.99 for 16 dollars and 99 cents. I want my pricing to be correct till cents. But while exporting it to csv, it truncates pricing by removing last zero in cases where cents are multiples of 10 (e.g. 16.50 turns into 16.5). Formatting it or even formatting and then parsing it as string does not help:

```
for col in df.columns:
    if col.__contains__('USD'):
        df[col] = '$'+df[col].round(decimals=2).astype(str).str.strip()
df.to_csv('pricing.txt', '\t')
```

No matter how any decimals I pass there as arguments it does not work. Current workaround is to write a separate function with conditional formatting but is there a way to do it via `pandas` itself.

Comment: Why does it matter? The value is still exactly the same. `$16.5` is still 16 dollars and 50 cents...

Comment: As I mentioned its pricing.

Comment: but the value is **exactly the same**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this (if you have float in in your column):

```
df[col] = df[col].map('${:,.2f}'.format)
```

Comment: Cant believe that simple! Just to mention if anyone stumble across. `round()` only truncates. However, such formatting ensures strict number of decimals either by truncating or by padding

Comment: I tried this solution, and it returns a text string like '$16.50' but I still need it in numerical float format...to match SQL Server field type...